# How to mock method which is called from another method

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, moq

Lets say I have this

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{ 
  public string GetSomething();
}

public class Sample : ISomeInterface
{
   public string GetSomething()
    {
        return "HELLO";
    }

    public string MethodToTest()
    {
        return GetSomething();
    }
}
```

I need to mock

```
GetSomething()
```

in order to change string output of

```
MethodToTest()
```

So I did this:

```
var mockClientConfigExtensions = new Mock<ISomeInterface>();
        mockClientConfigExtensions.Setup(ss => ss.GetSomething()).Returns("DDDD");
        var _os = new Sample();
        var k = _os.MethodToTest();


        Assert.Equal("DDDD", k);
```

The problem is 
    GetSomething()

still returns HELLO instead of mocking it.
How do I mock GetSomething(); ?

Comment: You're declaring and setting up a Mock but then using a normal instance of `Sample`. You're Mocking `GetSomething` just fine, you're just never using it.

Comment: So what should I change in order it to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mocked interface with the Setup is `mockClientConfigExtensions`, but the instance you are testing, `k`, is a concrete type and completely different to the one you performed a Setup on.

This is not how you should be mocking. Usually you would mock dependencies of the class under test and then perform setups on those.

If you really must mock the class under test, then you need to actually setup the methods on a concrete instance not on the interface. You also need to make the methods you want to mock virtual. e.g:

```
public class Sample : ISomeInterface
{
   public virtual string GetSomething()
    {
        return "HELLO";
    }

    public string MethodToTest()
    {
        return GetSomething();
    }
}

...

var mockSample = new Mock<Sample>();
mockSample.Setup(s => s.GetSomething()).Returns("mystring");
Assert.Equal("mystring", mockSample.Object.MethodToTest());
```

https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Comment: Is that necessary to set it as override?

Comment: Yes, if you want to mock a method on a concrete type it needs to be virtual: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Comment: Just a quick observation - on the final line of the sample, I assume `s` is intended to be `mockSample`?

Comment: @LordWilmore good spot, thank you. Typed it out quickly without IDE.

Comment: In last line, should it be `mockSample.Object.MethodToTest`?

Comment: Also, doesn't the mock need to be initiated with { CallBase = true }, so that the real method is invoked?

var mockSample = new Mock<Sample>() { CallBase = true };